# Convert minutes to hh: mm format

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object that takes several minutes, like int numbers.

Is there a way to pass this int number (minutes) into the date format?

I tried to use the angular date pipe but the conversion is wrong.

Can someone help me?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1x2efz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
 <div *ngFor="let m of data">
<p>{{m.minutes * 1000 | date:'HH:mm'}}</p>   
 </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your minutes to milliseconds.

```html
 <div *ngFor="let m of data">
<p>{{m.minutes * 1000 * 60| date:'HH:mm':'UTC'}}</p>   
 </div>
```

According to the [documentation for the pipe´s value](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value):

The date expression: a Date object, a number (**milliseconds** since UTC epoch), or an ISO string (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Comment: Can you precise that?
Is it shifted?

Comment: Added UTC-Timezone for removing time shift caused by your local timezone.

Comment: Word of warning: This will not work if your duration is larger than 24 hours - it will cycle. So if you have e.g. 26 hours, it will show "02:00". So even though this would be the most elegant solution, it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this , You can pass dynamic values to your need

```
function timeConvert(n:number) {
    var num = n;
    var hours = (num / 60);
    var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
    var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
    var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
    return num + " minutes = " + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s).";
  }

    console.log(timeConvert(200));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by changing your code as follows.
**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let m of data">
    <p>{{ math.floor(m.minutes / 60) | number: '2.'}}:{{m.minutes % 60 | number: '2.'}}</p>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
 data=[ your data here ]
 math = Math;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vvd8h2)

I hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
pad(m.minutes/60) + ":" + pad(m.minutes%60)
```

with the padding function:

```
function pad(d) {
    return (d < 10) ? '0' + d.toString() : d.toString();
}
```

PS: it's not going to be a date object, but it will display the time as in your examples :)

PS2: you can change it to:

```
pad((m.minutes/60).toFixed(0)) + ":" + pad(m.minutes%60)
```

to get rid of the extra decimals if this was the problem

Comment: Convert hours well (60, 120 etc.) but if you have minutes like (5) it will no longer work correctly

Comment: you can change it to: 

pad((m.minutes/60).toFixed(0)) + ":" + pad(m.minutes%60) 

to get rid of the extra decimals if this was the problem